# HTML5 slogan as heading in eshop

Tags: html, seo, semantic-markup, outline, heading

How do I make a document outline like this using HTML5 semantic tags, when I need the first two headings in one block?

```
-MySite
--Books for children
---Book1
---Book2
```

When I use

```html
<body>
 <header class="INeedThisInOneBox">
  <h1>MySite</h1>
   <h2 class="slogan">Books for children</h2>
 </header>
  <article>
   <h1>Book1</h1>
  </article>
  <article>
   <h1>Book2</h1>
  </article>
</body>
```

the outline goes:

```
-MySite
--Books for children
--Book1
--Book2
```

I would like to use semantic tags, but need to have SEO importance granted for the slogan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only get this outline if you stop using sectioning content elements (example A) or if you start using sectioning content elements everytime when it’s appropriate (example B).

Example A: no sectioning content elements

```html
<body>

  <header>
    <h1>MySite</h1>
    <h2>Books for children</h2>
  </header>

  <div>
    <h3>Book1</h3>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h3>Book2</h3>
  </div>

</body>
```

Example B: sectioning content elements everywhere

```html
<body>

  <header>
    <h1>MySite</h1>
  </header>

  <section>

    <h2>Books for children</h2>

    <article>
     <h3>Book1</h3>
    </article>

    <article>
     <h3>Book2</h3>
    </article>

  </section>

</body>
```

I wouldn’t advise to use example A. Example B is the correct way to mark this up (and I’d challenge your assumption that you would need to do this differently for SEO, but discussing SEO is off-topic on Stack Overflow).

Comment: Thanks, I would love to use example B as you suggest, but as I asked, can I then have h1 and h2 in one container? This container (INeedThisInOneBox in my code) has only styling purpose.

Comment: @Fanky: AFAIK not without including the whole `section` in this container, too.

Comment: So it sounds like the answer is "No, you can't" and I'm starting to hate HTML5 semantic markup :)

Comment: @Fanky: Well, with example A you can ;-) -- Anyway, are you sure that you really need this for your styling requirements? There might be another way to achieve the desired styling. It seems to be rather uncommon to have the site heading together with the main content heading in the same element next to each other.

Comment: Well, it's the head-part of the page - which tells the user 1)the brand 2)what the brand does. I'll consider to wrap the info in one heading then: `<h1>MySite - Books for children</h1>`

Comment: @Fanky: Should be doable even with example B, I guess: don’t style the `section` (add a `div` inside the `section`, and style this to make a different from the header), and make the `h2` visually part of the site header. You could of course create a separate question if you have problems implementing it with CSS.